# Getting large Data (>256 MB) in a http.get

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I need to recieve large data in a http get request from my rest server. The data on backend side is ok.
When the length of data is greater than 256 MB i get no results in my front end side.

The request in front end:

```
GetProduktionsdaten(start_datum:string, end_datum:string,    station:number, stationBeschreibung:string, intervall:string, chk_Linie1:boolean, chk_Linie2:boolean):Observable<ProduktionsDaten>
{
    const url = urlbase + '0/produktionsdaten';
    return this.httpc.get<ProduktionsDaten>(url,
{
  params:
  {
    'startdatum':start_datum,
    'enddatum':end_datum,
    'station': station.toString(),
    'stationBeschreibung': stationBeschreibung,
    'intervall':intervall,
    'chkLinie1':this.boolToString(chk_Linie1),
    'chkLinie2':this.boolToString(chk_Linie2)
  }
}
).pipe(tap(ProduktionsDaten => console.log("o.k.")), catchError(this.handleError));
```

}

How can i get data above 256 MB?

Comment: Why would you download 256 MB in a clientside application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

Comment: What exaclty means " i get no results in my front end side"? Any errors in browser console? But anyway, you can download files of this size (= save to disk) but I guess you'll never be able to build a usable application if you want to load all those data in a JavaScript variable. How about paging?